# How to SSH into a Kubernetes Node or Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How to SSH into a Kubernetes Node or Server hosted on AWS?
I have hosted a Kubernetes Server and Node on AWS. I'm able to see the nodes and server from my local laptop with the kubectl get node command.

I need to create a persistent volume for my node but I'm unable to ssh into it.

Is there any specific way to ssh into the node or server?

Comment: How do you normally SSH into your AWS VM? How did you create the Kubernetes node in the first place?

Comment: This is not related to Google Kubernetes Engine rather it is related to AWS. I have removed GKE tag from this question.

Comment: ssh core@NODE_IP_ADDRESS -i ~/.ssh/CREDS_FILE_FOR_ACCOUNT

Answer (score 22):

Use
`kubectl ssh node NODE_NAME`

This kubectl addon is from here. https://github.com/luksa/kubectl-plugins.
And I have verified that. This works similarly to the `oc` command in openshift.

P.S. This is connecting inside of a freshly created pod on the specified node. In that sense, you do not get access to node itself (as you wanted) but (just) a `privileged` pod

Comment: Didn't work for me. Kustomize Version: v4.5.4

Comment: @HamzaSaeed Hi, this is just some shell and some yaml files to deploy additional pod when to ssh. Not sure any relationship with kustomize. Some error log may help debug.

Comment: Is there any way around it? I don't wanna use third party plugins on my production cluster due to security reasons.

Comment: @HamzaSaeed  Have you ever checked the file https://github.com/luksa/kubectl-plugins/blob/master/kubectl-ssh? It is just lines of bash and yaml. You can inspect it line by line within 5 minutes and remove the harmful code as you can if you can find any. 
Furthermore, just use the same idea to write a kubeclt plugin is simple. You can write on on your own. This is what I can do here.

Comment: IMPORTANT: this addon will NOT execute in the context of the requested node but rather in the context of a newly created pod on that node

Comment: I do not recommend this plugin, because it uses a highly privileged security context, which should be authorized on your cluster (container isolation breakout, anc chroot in mounter host file system).

Answer (score 10):

Try this:
`ssh -i <path of the private key file> admin@<ip of the aws kube instances>`

The perm file should be in $HOME/.ssh/kube_rsa

Comment: Yeah, Thats exactly how i usually login to the other VM's. But this one simply fails.

ssh -i "AWS_key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-54-177-**-***.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-54-177-**-***.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: Try to modify your security group. Refer: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=66813

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this on AWS specifically, but you can get a shell onto a Node using the following trick.

If you need access to the underlying Nodes for your Kubernetes cluster (and you don't have direct access - usually if you are hosting Kubernetes elsewhere), you can use the following deployment to create Pods where you can login with `kubectl exec`, and you have access to the Node's IPC and complete filesystem under `/node-fs`. To get a node console that is just like you have SSHd in, after logging in, perform `chroot /node-fs`. It is inadvisable to keep this running, but if you need access to the node, this will help. Because it is a DaemonSet, it starts one of these Pods on each Node.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: privpod
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      mydaemon: privpod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        mydaemon: privpod
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      hostPID: true
      hostIPC: true
      containers:
        - name: privcontainer
          image: johnnyb61820/network-toolkit
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          command:
            - tail
            - "-f"
            - /dev/null
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nodefs
              mountPath: /node-fs
            - name: devfs
              mountPath: /dev
      volumes:
        - name: nodefs
          hostPath:
            path: / 
        - name: devfs
          hostPath:
            path: /dev
```

This is from Appendix C.13 of [Cloud Native Applications with Docker and Kubernetes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484288750).  I've found this useful especially if I need to deal with physical drives or something similar.  It's not something you should leave running, but helps when you are in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

### 2024 - Update

**With some new capabilities added to K8S you can now shell into a node in a very convenient way with `kubectl`.**

From [Debugging via a shell on the node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#node-shell-session):

Find the Node on which the Pod is running and create a Pod running on the Node. 
To create an interactive shell on a Node using kubectl debug, run:

```
kubectl debug node/mynode -it --image=ubuntu
```

When creating a debugging session on a node, keep in mind that:

- `kubectl` debug automatically generates the name of the new Pod based on the name of the Node.
- The root filesystem of the Node will be mounted at `/host`.
- The container runs in the host IPC, Network, and PID namespaces, although the pod isn't privileged, so reading some process information may fail, and chroot `/host` may fail.
- If you need a privileged pod, create it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes nodes can be accessed similar way how we ssh into other linux machines. Just try ssh with the external ip of that node and you can login into it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If worker nodes are in private subnet, you can use bastion host with ssh agent forwarding as defined in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/